# Display value of :set option 

Tags: vim

If you don't give `:colorscheme` an argument then it shows the name of the colorscheme that vim is currently using. Is there a similar way in vim to show if an option is set or what the value of the option is set to if it isn't a boolean? For example, if I wanted to know whether `autoindent` is set or I wanted to know the value of `textwidth`, how would I find that?

Comment: There are several `set` related goodies you can find at `:help set`.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Use the `:set` command.

- `:set autoindent?` prints the option, and its value, if any. Vim *toggle options* (booleans, options that are on/off), like `autoindent`, are prefixed with `no` to indicate that they're turned off, so `:set autoindent?` will display `autoindent` or `noautoindent`.
- `:set autoindent` turns `autoindent` on.

  - this form turns toggle options *on*
  - for number or string options, this shows the value of the option, so `:set textwidth` will also print the value of the option. For number or string options, `:set option` is equivalent to `:set option?`.
- `:set autoindent!` inverts the option. `autoindent` becomes `noautoindent`.
- `:set autoindent&` reverts `autoindent` to its default value.
- Set number or string options with `:set option=value`, e.g. `set tabstop=3`

Comment: `:set optiont&` - `t` is  typo?

Comment: thanks @johnc.j. It _was_ a typo, and the edit gave me the opportunity to make the answer a little more clear: `option` is a confusing placeholder

Answer (score 16):

Use `:set textwidth?` to show the value of `textwidth`.

Use `:verbose set textwidth?` to show where this value was last set.

In general, you can add `?` after the setting name to show its current value.

Answer (score 6):

You can learn [ways to query options](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Displaying_the_current_Vim_environment) from vim-wiki. You can list all options with `:set all`.